# Automatically generated /etc/hosts is wrong

Tags: networking, centos, centos5, kickstart, anaconda

I've created a kickstart script to install CentOS 5.5 (32bit) in a fully automated way.

The DNS/DHCP setup correctly gives the system the right hostname in both the forward and reverse lookups.

*dig node4.mydomain.com.  +short*

```
10.10.10.64
```

*dig -x 10.10.10.64 +short*

```
node4.mydomain.com.
```

In the state the installed system is right after the installation completed is as follows:

*cat /etc/sysconfig/network*

```
NETWORKING=yes
NETWORKING_IPV6=yes
GATEWAY=10.10.10.1
HOSTNAME=node4.mydomain.com
```

*echo ${HOSTNAME}*

```
node4.mydomain.com
```

*cat /etc/hosts*

```
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1               localhost.localdomain localhost
::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
10.10.10.64            node4
```

My problem is that this automatically generated hosts file is slightly different from the way I want it (or better: the way Hadoop wants it).

The last line should look like this:

```
10.10.10.64            node4.mydomain.com node4
```

What do I modify where to fix this?

Thanks.

---

Edit: 
I've tried to find the code that actually creates this file. I've had a look inside the acaconda sources and the setup src rpm but it wasn't done from one of those.
Does anyone here know where to code is located that creates the /etc/hosts file?

---

I added the following to the %post of my kickstart file which works for my situation:

```
# =========================
# Force the right hosts file for Hadoop and such
cat > /etc/hosts <<End-of-file
# Do not remove the following line, or various programs
# that require network functionality will fail.
127.0.0.1     localhost.localdomain localhost
::1           localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
\$(dig +short \$(hostname))      \$(hostname -f) \$(hostname -s)
End-of-file
```

Comment: Check that the DHCP server is actually returning a Domain Name (option 15). I do the same setup and /etc/hosts is formatted correctly.

Comment: @embobo: I'm using dnsmasq for this setup: What's the best way to check that the DHCP server really does this correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not being familiar with RedHat's kickstart system, I would use a supplemental script to run at the end of installation and set the line the way you want.

Comment: Thanks, see the bottom of my question on how I actually did it.